# Lua patterns to replace multiple semicolons

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I got this string in a Lua script:

```
one;two;;three;four;;five;;six;seven;
```

The first char will never be a semicolon. The middle separators can be a single or double semicolon, and the last char can be or not a single semicolon.

Using the Lua patterns (and `string.gsub()`): How can I match the double semicolons in the middle to replace those with a single one AND delete the last optional semicolon?

The output must be like this:

```
one;two;three;four;five;six;seven
```

Is this possible using a single pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one pattern to replace multiple `;` to single `;`, and another to remove the last `;` is like this

```
local str = "one;two;;three;four;;five;;six;seven;"
local result = str:gsub(';+', ';'):gsub(';*$', '')
```

One possible way to use a single pattern is like this:

```
local result = (str .. ";;;"):gsub(";+", function(s) 
                                             if s == ";" or s == ";;" then 
                                                 return ";" 
                                             else 
                                                 return "" 
                                             end 
                                         end)
```

What I'm trying to do is to append three `;` to the end of the string, so any one or two `;` should be replaced with one `;`. And more `;`(could be three or four and it must be at the end) is replaced to empty string.

I would prefer the solution with two patterns as it's more clear.

Comment: Right now im using `tempString:gsub(';+', ';'):gsub(';*$', '')`, but i wondering if exist a single pattern approach

Comment: @AlvaroFuentesZurita That's the same as what I would write. Using a single pattern is possible, I added one solution, but I'll prefer using two patterns as it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function remove_extra_delim(s, delim)
    local t = {}
    for each in s:gmatch("[^"..delim.."]+") do
        table.insert(t, each)
    end
    return table.concat(t, delim)
end

teststr = "one;two;;three;four;;five;;six;seven;"
print(remove_extra_delim(teststr, ";"))
```

Outputs:

> one;two;three;four;five;six;seven

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of semicolons is either 1 or 2, you can simply do

```
string:gsub(";;", ";")
```

Otherwise, the other answers will do.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hacky, but it does the trick:

```
x = test:gsub(";+(.?)",
  function(a)
    if a == "" then
      return ""
    else
      return ";" .. a
    end
  end)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I'm following your description exactly, so these will match one or two ; but not more than two, and final zero or one ; but not more than one)

```
-- Method one uses two patterns but it's simpler and my preferred one
s = 'one;two;;three;four;;five;;six;seven;'
s = s:gsub(';;',';'):gsub(';?$','')
print(s)

-- Method two uses one pattern (if you really MUST use only one pattern)
s = 'one;two;;three;four;;five;;six;seven;'
s = (s..';'):gsub(';;',';')
s = s:sub(1,#s-1)
print(s)
```